# Preseed automatic partitioning

Tags: ubuntu, partition, supermicro, preseed

I'm using the following `partman` settings for automated installs of VMs for some years now:

```
d-i partman-auto/disk string /dev/sda
d-i partman-auto/method string regular
d-i partman-lvm/device_remove_lvm boolean true
d-i partman-md/device_remove_md boolean true
d-i partman-lvm/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/alignment string "optimal"
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string                         \
      boot-root ::                                            \
              64 512 300% linux-swap                          \
                      $primary{ }                             \
                      method{ swap } format{ }                \
              .                                               \
              500 10000 1000000000 ext4                       \
                      $primary{ } $bootable{ }                \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                      mountpoint{ / }                         \
              .
d-i partman/confirm_write_new_label boolean true
d-i partman/choose_partition select finish
d-i partman/confirm boolean true
d-i partman/confirm_nooverwrite boolean true
```

This creates a small swap partition at the beginning and uses the rest of the disk for the root partition. This works well and allows easy partition extension when I need to increase the size of the virtual disk.

Now I'm trying to adapt this recipe to install a number of identical bare metal servers. To do that I just switched the partitions and set the sizes to more reasonable values for a machine with 256GB RAM and 460GB system disk (SSDs in a hardware RAID1, but that shouldn't matter):

```
  boot-root ::                                            \
          32768 65536 1000000000 ext4                     \
                  $primary{ } $bootable{ }                \
                  method{ format } format{ }              \
                  use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                  mountpoint{ / }                         \
          .                                               \
          16384 16384 65536 linux-swap                    \
                  $primary{ }                             \
                  method{ swap } format{ }                \
          .
```

The rest of the `partman*` directives are identical.

As far as I understand the documentation (and additional [posts like this](https://www.bishnet.net/tim/blog/2015/01/29/understanding-partman-autoexpert_recipe/)) this should create a large root partition that spans nearly the entire disk, with a swap partition between 16 and 64 GB at the end.

Well, it doesn't. It creates a 450MB partition, followed by a 460GB swap partition.

[image]

When I install the same machine with the preseed for VMs, the partitions are created properly as defined in the preseed file:

[image]

So, what am I doing wrong with the recipe for the bare metal machine?

If it matters, the install iso is based on the Ubuntu 16.04.5 server iso.

Output of `fdisk /dev/sda` and `parted /dev/sda print`:

[image]

Some more variants I tried:

```
# this belongs to tha last block, as suggested by @Peter
#d-i partman-basicfilesystems/choose_label string gpt
#d-i partman-basicfilesystems/default_label string gpt
#d-i partman-partitioning/choose_label string gpt
#d-i partman-partitioning/default_label string gpt
#d-i partman/choose_label string gpt
#d-i partman/default_label string gpt

d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string                         \
      boot-root ::                                            \
##########################
              65536 1 -1 ext4                             \
                      $primary{ } $bootable{ }                \
                      method{ format } format{ }              \
                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
                      mountpoint{ / }                         \
              .                                               \
              65536 65536 65536 linux-swap                    \
                      $primary{ }                             \
                      method{ swap } format{ }                \
              .                                               
##########################
#              1 1 -1 ext4                             \
#                      $primary{ } $bootable{ }                \
#                      method{ format } format{ }              \
#                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
#                      mountpoint{ / }                         \
#              .                                               \
#              65536 65536 65536 linux-swap                    \
#                      $primary{ }                             \
#                      method{ swap } format{ }                \
#              .                                               
##########################
#              32768 50 5242880 ext4                             \
#                      $primary{ } $bootable{ }                \
#                      method{ format } format{ }              \
#                      use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
#                      mountpoint{ / }                         \
#              .                                               \
#              16384 100 65536 linux-swap                    \
#                      $primary{ }                             \
#                      method{ swap } format{ }                \
#              .                                               
##########################
# use along with the annoted partman-* directives above
#              538 538 1075 free                           \
#                      $iflabel{ gpt }                     \
#                      $reusemethod{ }                     \
#                      method{ efi }                       \
#                            format{ }                     \
#              .                                           \
#              1 1 -1 ext4                                 \
#                  $primary{ } $bootable{ }                \
#                  method{ format } format{ }              \
#                  use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
#                  mountpoint{ / }                         \
#              .                                           \
#              65536 65536 65536 linux-swap                \
#                  $primary{ }                             \
#                  method{ swap } format { }               \              .                         
#              .
```

It doesn't make a difference, the resulting root partition always has only 453MB.

Comment: Did you try to set the maximum size for the root-fs to `-1`? Please also add the output of `parted /dev/sda print` or `fdisk -l /dev/sda`, not sure which tool is available during install.

Comment: you should change every time you said "kickstart" to "preseed" (title, tags, and body) ... for some reason there is partial (and terrible and unusable in my experience) kickstart support in Ubuntu, so your title is misleading, but you are clearly using preseed, not kickstart. Kickstart is a Redhat thing.

Comment: @Thomas the installer provides no useful command for that that I could find, but I bootet a rescue environment and could use both tools there. I added the output. And yes, I also tried `-1` as maximum value.

Comment: @Peter thanks for the pointer, I don't know how I mixed those two up. Of course it's preseed. I guess I installed to much CentOS lately. Changed.

Comment: Can you try to set the priority of the root partition to an arbitrary high value above the max size.

Comment: I already did that. No difference.

Comment: are you sure it's using your new preseed file? How do you deliver it to the machine? I like to put it in the netboot initrd image because then it has no dependencies on network, etc. and find that works great.

Comment: Ok, this is somewhat embarrassing. All the time I had the wrong image mounted on the server I was working on. See my answer on why I didn't notice this before. @Peter, thanks for pointing me in that direction. If you want to add this in your answer, or write a different answer about *Check if you work with the right image. Check again. And again.* I'll be happy to award the bounty to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

The wrong image was mounted. Thanks to @Peter for pointing me that way.

**The long story:**

After Peters comment I rechecked my whole iso build pipeline, the .seed files, the isolinux txt.cfg, the custom bootlogo, the bash script that builds the .iso, finding nothing wrong. I changed the .preseed file again, this time adding a third partition that should be mounted as `/var`, rebuilt the image, clicked on "Unmount" and "Mount" in the BMC interface of the server, rebooted, ran the installation, and guess what, it was the same layout as before, no additional partition. Becoming suspicious I checked `/target/etc/issue`:

```
Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
```

That should have been 16.04.5. During my installation tests I recreated the Ubuntu .iso completely, basing it on 16.04.5 instead of the previous 16.04.1 (resulting in a different iso name, because the .iso file contains the version number).

I have two ways of mounting ISO images on those SuperMicro boards. I can connect to a single BMC and mount the ISO there, or I can use the SuperMicro Server Manager to mount an ISO on multiple machines at once. I had a number of machines to install, so naturally I used the SSM method and mounted the ISO everywhere.

After changing to 16.04.5 I only changed the filename directly in the BMC of the host I was working on and remounted it. I only get `There is an iso file mounted.` as a confirmation, no more details.

Clicking on the `Save` button on the mount image page results in this error message:

[image]

I did not enter the path this way, this was set by the Server Manager, so I assumed it was correct. Apparently it isn't. After this I remounted the .iso file with the Server Manager instead on the BMC directly, and voila ...

[image]

Exactly what I had configured to test this.

The moral of the story: I wasted about a week of my time (and some of the valuable time of you helpful people) just because of the stupidity of a cheap BMC interface. Keep that in mind and recheck EVERYTHING when you run into unexplainable problems.

Comment: We are also using supermicro machines. We have a cluster of 120 machines installed with preseed... but I don't use any of the supermicro stuff for that (except accessing the keyboard and screen remotely and rebooting them). I just use a regular DHCP and tftp netboot install. And I like it that way... and I can also deliver a GRUB2 menu of multiple other installers and images I can run for other machines, supermicro or not. Next time I suggest you consider doing something like that.

Answer (score 9):

**Special notes**

It wasn't mentioned whether there is bios_grub, ESP, GPT or MBR, or which method the firmware uses. When using GPT, you need one or the other (or both). So what will happen is the installer will choose for you, based on some unknown criteria, likely related to disk size. To force using GPT, you can set things like this (which I remember not necessarily always working, despite using all 6 methods I found here):

```
d-i partman-basicfilesystems/choose_label string gpt
d-i partman-basicfilesystems/default_label string gpt
d-i partman-partitioning/choose_label string gpt
d-i partman-partitioning/default_label string gpt
d-i partman/choose_label string gpt
d-i partman/default_label string gpt
```

For example, for bios_grub, you would set:

```
    1 1 1 free                          \
        $primary{}                      \
        $bios_boot{}                    \
        method{ biosgrub }              \
    .                                   \
```

(I didn't put an `$iflabel{ gpt }` in there, and that can be useful because if anything goes wrong and you later convert it from MBR to GPT, you want the reserved space)

And for EFI (shamelessly copying and pasting from [Preseeding debian install - EFI](https://serverfault.com/questions/722021/preseeding-debian-install-efi) and didn't remove the iflabel):

```
    538 538 1075 free
        $iflabel{ gpt }
        $reusemethod{ }
        method{ efi }
        format{ } .
```

**And to answer the question**

To use the remainder, you use `-1`, not an arbitrarily hugely big number, and then just set the other numbers to bogus values like 1. And I wouldn't trust the ranges either... I just use a different preseed file for different hardware, not debian's automagic stuff. So I set it as only 65536, not a range.

```
d-i partman-auto/expert_recipe string               \
    boot-root ::                                    \
        1 1 -1 ext4                                 \
            $primary{ } $bootable{ }                \
            method{ format } format{ }              \
            use_filesystem{ } filesystem{ ext4 }    \
            mountpoint{ / }                         \
        .                                           \
        65536 65536 65536 linux-swap                \
            $primary{ }                             \
            method{ swap } format { }               \
        .
```

And make sure it's **really** using your new preseed file. I like to put it in the netboot initrd image because then it has no dependencies on network, etc. and find that works great. If you change something like the above, and it doesn't work, check it again, and again. If it's http/tftp, check the http/tftp logs or tcpdump. Or make a change that you will surely notice, and see if it did it.

If it's initrd, look in the initrd and see if it's really there. For example:

```
cd emptydir
gunzip -c path_to_initrd | cpio -i
# It must be named "preseed.cfg" if it's in the initrd.
cat preseed.cfg
```

Comment: I didn't even consider GPT, because the root drive is less than 1TB in size. Nevertheless I tried your suggestions (see the edit in the question), it didn't make a difference. And yes, I already had tried `-1` as max value earlier. The arbitrary high numbers were suggestions I found in multiple places, so I tried them.